# Is this an adequate formalization of non-trivial necessary and sufficient conditions?

Tags: logic, definition

In math papers, there is often the task of finding necessary and sufficient conditions for some open sentence $P$. Of course, $P$ itself is a necessary and sufficient condition for $P$. But that is trivial. I believe I have come up with an adequate formalization of non-trivial necessary and sufficient conditions for an open sentence $P$ in some first-order theory $T$, for instance $ZFC$. First of all, recall that $ZFC$ is not simply a bunch of set-theoretic axioms, but also first-order axioms and propositional axioms and inference rules. I define an open sentence $Q$ to be a non-trivial necessary and sufficient condition for $P$ if the equivalence $P \leftrightarrow Q$ can be proven in $ZFC$, but cannot be proven using propositional axioms and first order axioms. So, for example $(P \vee P)$ is a trivial necessary and sufficient condition for $P$, because it can be proven in propositional logic alone, and so is $(P \land (x=x))$, because it can be proven in first-order logic alone. Is this an adequate formalization of this intuitive notion? If not, can someone give me some counter-examples to this definition?

Comment: Well, I don't know that your intuitive notion of "non-trivial necessary and sufficient condition" is the same as mine, so this is very much a judgment call. I would say that the real meaning of this phrase is that the conditions tell us something meaningful about $P$ that we didn't already know. Of course manipulations using first-order logic which are valid for arbitrary $P$ don't have this property, since, by virtue of being valid for arbitrary $P$, they can't tell us anything about a specific $P$. So I agree that those should be excluded. But are there others? Not sure.

Comment: Personally, I don't think this intuitive notion needs to be formalized, nor does it help us do anything mathematical to formalize it. That being said, your definition seems reasonable to me. Test case: $P$ is "$n^2$ is even" and $Q$ is "$n$ is even". This is nontrivial according to your definition, and I think it counts as a nontrivially helpful mathematical fact, even though the proof is super simple.